# Tensor with upper indiced vs lower indices.

Tags: matrices, tensors

I am given the tensor $$X^{\mu v}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}2 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 1 & -2\end{array}\right)$$

I am asked to find the component $X_\nu ^\mu$ so for my understanding it should be just $$X_\nu ^\mu=X^{\mu \rho}X_{\rho \nu}=\delta_\nu ^\mu$$ and my explantation is that I am doing inverse operation (raising and than lowering the same indice). If I am wrong in my answer can you please tell me how should I think on the operation $X^{\mu \rho}X_{\rho \nu}$ and what is the elemnt of $X_{ \mu\nu}$ looks like?

Comment: $X^\mu_{\,\,\nu}=X^{\mu\gamma}g_{\gamma\nu}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{X}&=X^{ij}\phantom{.}\boldsymbol{g}_{i}\otimes\boldsymbol{g}_{j}\\
&=X^{ij}g_{jk}\phantom{.}\boldsymbol{g}_{i}\otimes\boldsymbol{g}^{k}\\
&=X^{i}_{k}\phantom{.}\boldsymbol{g}_{i}\otimes\boldsymbol{g}^{k}
\end{align}
$$

In other words, $X^{ij}g_{jk}=X^{i}_{k}$. Recall that $g_{ij}=\boldsymbol{g}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{g}_{j}$